# Spring LDAP - multiple bases in one or more request(s)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-data-ldap

I need to make a query that will search for all users, located in two different OUs.

For example :

```
base1: "OU=ou2,OU=ou1"
base2 : "OU=ou3,OU=ou1"
```

How can I do this with **LdapTemplate** ? I'm using *Spring Boot 3.1.1* and Spring Ldap.

I'd like to be able to do this in a single query, but I understand that this isn't possible. If I run two queries, would it be possible to merge the results without having to manually re-sort?

Many thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I applied (for a searching by Fullname, for example) :

```
public List<User> findAllByFullname(String fullname) {      
    LdapQuery query1 = getFullnameQuery(User.BASE1, fullname);
    LdapQuery query2 = getFullnameQuery(User.BASE2, fullname);

    List<User> users1 = ldapTemplate.find(query1,User.class);
    List<User> users2 = ldapTemplate.find(query2,User.class);
    
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.addAll(users1);
    users.addAll(users2);

    Collections.sort(users, Comparator.comparing(User::getFullname));
    
    return users;
}

private LdapQuery getUsernameQuery(String base, String username) {
    return LdapQueryBuilder.query().base(base).where("sAMAccountName").is(username);
}
```

This is clearly not ideal, so don't hesitate if you have a better solution. Thank you.